# Find the count of the first character of `Name` across all values then sort it ( PostgreSQL )

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following rows:

```
key Name
 1   Mighty
 2   Jon
 3   Jaine
 4   Arya
```

Now I want to count each non case-sensitive occurrence of the first character of all `NAME`s in the table, then sort the result in descending order. If there is a tie (counts are equal for a multiple characters), it should sort the result in alphabetical order, so my output looks like:

```
A 3
J 2
M 1
```

`A` exists 3 times, once in `Jaine` and twice in `Arya`.

Comment: This seems like a pretty basic `GROUP BY` query with a string function.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using left(name,1) but not able to figure out how should I iterate in rows to know the count.

Comment: A is repeated three times in the table , 1 "a" in "Jaine" and 2 "a" in Arya @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT LEFT(Name,1) AS letter, COUNT(*) As ct
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY LEFT(Name,1) 
ORDER BY ct DESC,letter
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, 1) AS letter, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY LEFT(Name, 1)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, letter;
```

### Demo

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause first sorts descending by the count, then sorts by first letter, should two or more letters be tied with the same count.

Answer (score 1):

This code produces the expected result. Tested in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). Data is assumed to be stored in table `table1`:

```
with first_letters as
(
    select
    upper(left(Name,1)) as letter_uppercase,
    count(*) as count_ignore
    from table1
    group by upper(left(Name,1))
),
occurrences as (
    select 
    t1.Name,
    length(t1.Name) - length(replace(upper(t1.Name), fl.letter_uppercase,'')) as occurrence
    from table1 t1
    inner join first_letters fl on fl.letter_uppercase = upper(left(t1.Name,1))
)
select
result.letter_uppercase,
sum(result.occurrence) as sum_occurrence
from
(
    select
    fl.letter_uppercase,
    o.occurrence
    from first_letters fl
    inner join occurrences o on upper(o.Name) like '%' || fl.letter_uppercase || '%' 
) result
 group by result.letter_uppercase
 order by sum(result.occurrence) desc,
          result.letter_uppercase;
```

Comment: From your output  A=3,J=2,M=1. Could you illustrate how the expected count of A is 3

Comment: Yes you are correct @a_horse_with_no_name. It is a non-reserved keyword and quotes are not required. Answer updated. As documented in the [Postgresql Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a list of all characters in the table, then a list of all first characters and then combine them both:

```
with all_chars as (
   select c
   from names, unnest(string_to_array(lower(name), null)) as t(c)
), first_chars as (
   select distinct lower(left(name,1)) as c
   from names
)
select fc.c, 
       (select count(*) from all_chars ac where ac.c = fc.c) as cnt
from first_chars fc
order by cnt desc, fc.c;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MTRRK31478